# can not understand with null and clear statement in this example

Tags: java, list

Sorry for my poor english, I test the List object with clear method and to assign null value

here is code

```
public class TestList {
private List<String> list;
private List<List<String>> mainList;

public TestList(){
    list = new ArrayList<String>();
    mainList = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
}
public static void main(String arg[]){
    String[] mylist = {"sunday","monda","tuesday","wednesday","thurday","friday","saturday"};

    TestList tl1 = new TestList();

    for(String s : mylist)
        tl1.list.add(s);


    tl1.mainList.add(tl1.list);

    //tl1.list.clear(); // here if clear then not getting the list

    tl1.list = null; ///// but here to assign null still getting list

    System.out.println("after clear");
    System.out.println();
    for(List<String> list : tl1.mainList){
        for(String s : list){
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }

}
 }
```

so my question is when I clear the tl1.list using tl1.list.clear(); and then print the value it's clear but when I assing null to this tl1.list then it will print the value how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tl1.list.clear()` clears the list `list` which was added to `mainList` as well. As Java is object-oriented `list` and `mainList.get(0)` reference exactly the same object. If you set `tl1.list` to null, you only dereference the object, it is still available in `mainList`.

I'm not sure if I understood your question, but I guess this is what you asked...

Comment: m asking this whatever you given the answer here, but still confuse when i assign the list as null then how to keep in the mainList? that should be null if i only go through the tl1.list in for loop then getting nullpointer exception but not with the tl1.mainList that was not understand

Comment: This is how object orientation works, you assign object references to variables. If you set a variable to null (`tl1.list = null`) you only remove the reference. Have a look at the [Java tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

Assigning a **null** to any collection does not mean that the elements associated with it will be removed. It only means that you no longer require that object anymore. Now it is up to garbage collector who then dereference this object. If there are lots of statements between the **null assignment** and **print statements** this may cause a problem since GC may get time to dereference it.
I hope my answer will help you understand this.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you are asking, maybe you think clear() deletes the object - that's not true, it makes the list empty.